# How do I create Stored Procedure in MSSQL without Management Studio?

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, export, ssms

I have a customer who is not interested in installing MSSQL Management Studio. And I need to add one Stored procedure in the Database for my application to communicate.

Is it possible to create the stored procedure in MSSQL Server without Management Studio?

FYI, I can export the .sql file for Stored procedure from my system.

---

## Solved

**Solutions based on the answers**:

- [SQLCMD](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/command-prompt-utility-reference-database-engine?view=sql-server-2014) (installed with SQL Server)
- [Azure Data Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/azure-data-studio/what-is?view=sql-server-2017)

Comment: Command line sqlcmd, tools ssdt

Comment: How did you set-up the database and how is the SQL Server instance managed? Use that software to run the script.

Comment: Or just connect to their database using the version installed on your laptop. What a strange situation. Sometimes clients can't be saved from themselves.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use...

1. SSDT (SQL Server Data Tools)
2. SQLCMD
3. PowerShell

Comment: SQLCMD is installed by default. That should work for me. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 1):

You could see if your client would be willing to install [Azure Data Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/azure-data-studio/download?view=sql-server-2017) (formerly SQL Operations Studio). It's a quicker install than SSMS.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning the tool.